# Export a React library with Webpack: export MyComponent not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, node-modules

I'm using Webpack 4.30.0, Babel 7 and React for building a **lib** (that works locally, thanks to Storybook). I will use this lib elsewhere. Here is the build configuration I use:

### .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

### package.json (sample)

```
{
  "name": "mylib",
  "version": "1.6.0",
  "main": "dist/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  }
}
```

### webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/"),
    publicPath: "",
    filename: "main.js",
    libraryTarget: "umd",
    umdNamedDefine: true,
    globalObject: "typeof self !== 'undefined' ? self : this"
  },
  externals: [
    {
      react: {
        root: "React",
        commonjs2: "react",
        commonjs: "react",
        amd: "react"
      },
      "react-dom": {
        root: "ReactDOM",
        commonjs2: "react-dom",
        commonjs: "react-dom",
        amd: "react-dom"
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

### src/index.js

```
import MyComponent from "./MyComponent";
// ...

export {
  MyComponent,
  // ...
}
```

When I try to import this lib elsewhere (in another project), it fails ("export MyComponent not found" or "undefined").

```
import { MyComponent } from "react-elasticsearch"; // FAILS
```

What can I do to make my export works?

Comment: I don't understand, you are exporting the `MyComponent` from `src/index.js` and you are trying to import it from `react-elasticsearch`??

Comment: @VikasSingh react-elasticsearch is just the name of the lib I created. The question is about a lib I create and I try to import it elsewhere. I edited the question to replace with "mylib"